# Should we add a technical tutorial to the FAQ?

Tags: discussion

I arrived here yesterday, and I am new to the StackExchange sites. What I miss is a technical tutorial about the site features. In particular, the following isssues have me confused:

- The difference between an Answer and a Comment. In particular, Markdown seems to be disallowed or restricted for comments (I tried putting a blockquote in my comment, and failed). Also, editing a comment seems to be on a timer, I can edit my comments immediatly after posting, but later I cannot.
- Community Wiki: What does it do?
- What happens if you delete a post you've made, for example in terms of reputation, and the comments on it?
- How does closing and re-opening work?

As far as I understand, some of these things can be changed (for example Markdown) by thwe moderators. When everything is more or less set up and we foresee no major changes to the site features, I think a tutorial explaning these things would be very helpful to newbies.

Also, answers to my specific questions above would be welcome.

Comment: Great idea. I'll create a FAQ page that is community wiki so we can all add questions we think need clarification.

Comment: Here's the link: http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/25/material-to-supplement-the-faq

Answer (score 2):

Being new to SE, I would appreciate this now, and I'm sure others in the future would as well.

For example, aside from reading comments on various "big list" questions referring to Community Wikis, I have no know idea how they work, and a search around the FAQ, etc. hasn't illuminated the question for me.